# How many Hobbit clans/families have 'feet' in their surnames?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkiens-legendarium, the-hobbit, names, hobbits

How many hobbit clans or families include feet in their last names?

According to the movies, it seems like every other clan seems to have feet in their last name.  Is this typical or is this just in the movies?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are a few, but far from the majority:

1. The **Proudfoot** family is invited to the special pavilion at Bilbo's Party:

   > There were many Bagginses and Boffins, and also many Tooks and Brandybucks; there were various Grubbs (relations of Bilbo Baggins' grandmother), and various Chubbs (connexions of his Took grandfather); and a selection of Burrowses, Bolgers, Bracegirdles, Brockhouses, Goodbodies, Hornblowers and Proudfoots.
   >
   > <sup><sub>*Fellowship of the Ring* Book I Chapter 1: "A Long-expected Party"</sub></sup>
2. Daddy **Twofoot** is one of the Gaffer's barmates:

   > 'And no wonder they're queer,' put in Daddy Twofoot (the Gaffer's next-door neighbour), 'If they live on the wrong side of the Brandywine River, and right agin the Old Forest. That's a dark bad place, if half the tales be true.'
   >
   > <sup><sub>*Fellowship of the Ring* Book I Chapter 1: "A Long-expected Party"</sub></sup>
3. Nina **Lightfoot** married into the Bolger family; her name appears in the Bolger family tree, which was dropped from the Appendices before publication<sup>1</sup>. Christopher Tolkien re-printed it in *The Peoples of Middle-earth*, and it's transcribed by the good people at [The Thain's Book](http://thainsbook.net/otherhobbits.html#Bolger-Tree) (hand-drawn circles added by me):

   [image]

   As you can see<sup>2</sup>, this means Nina is Frodo's second cousin, twice removed (by marriage)
4. The **Puddifoot**s are a farming family, neighbours of Farmer Maggot:

   > They went along the lane, until they saw the thatched roofs of a large house and farm-buildings peeping out among the trees ahead. The Maggots, and the Puddifoots of Stock, and most of the inhabitants of the Marish, were house-dwellers; and this farm was stoutly built of brick and had a high wall all round it. There was a wide wooden gate opening out of the wall into the lane.
   >
   > <sup><sub>*Fellowship of the Ring* Book I Chapter 4: "A Short Cut to Mushrooms"</sub></sup>

   Reports that the Puddifoot matriarch ran [a tea shop remain](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Madam_Puddifoot%27s_Tea_Shop) unconfirmed.
5. Will **Whitfoot** is the long-serving Mayor of Hobbiton:

   > Big Folk could hardly beg for lodgings in hobbit-holes. They were more interested in Sam and Pippin, who were now feeling quite at home, and were chatting gaily about events in the Shire. Pippin roused a good deal of laughter with an account of the collapse of the roof of the Town Hole in Michel Delving: Will Whitfoot, the Mayor, and the fattest hobbit in the Westfarthing, had been buried in chalk, and came out like a floured dumpling.
   >
   > <sup><sub>*Fellowship of the Ring* Book I Chapter 9: "At the Sign of *The Prancing Pony*"</sub></sup>

But this is a pretty small percentage of the total Hobbit families; there are dozens of hobbit surnames given in Tolkien's writings.

Worth a mention are the **Harfoot**s, though they're not, strictly speaking, either a family or a clan. The Harfoots were one of the original three "breeds" of hobbit:

> Before the crossing of the mountains the Hobbits had already become divided into three somewhat different breeds: Harfoots, Stoors, and Fallohides. The Harfoots were browner of skin, smaller, and shorter, and they were beardless and bootless; their hands and feet were neat and nimble; and they preferred highlands and hillsides.
>
> <sup><sub>*Fellowship of the Ring* Prologue 1: "Concerning Hobbits"</sub></sup>

### The Movies

Only one of the above families is mentioned by name in the *Lord of the Rings* trilogy<sup>3</sup>: the Proudfoots:

> **Bilbo** *(clearing his throat)* My dear Bagginses and Boffins, Tooks and Brandybucks... Grubbs, Chubbs, Burrowses, Hornblowers, Bolgers, Bracegirdles, Goodbodies, Brockhouses, and Proodfoots...
>
> **Proudfoot** ProudFEET!
>
> <sup><sub>*The Fellowship of the Ring* (2001)</sub></sup>

Interestingly, Daddy Twofoot also appears in the film, in the Hobbiton montage that plays over Bilbo's opening narration. Although he isn't named in the film, he's identified in the film-licensed trading card game:

[image]

He also has a speaking role in the Extended Edition, in the *Green Dragon* pub, though I don't believe the role is credited.

---

<sup>1</sup> The family tree was restored to the Appendices for the 50th anniversary edition of the book, along with the Boffin family tree

<sup>2</sup> I'm very impressed if you can actually see this; I had to draw a simplified family tree and do a frankly embarrassing amount of arithmetic to get there. If you want to work it out for yourself, [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PM79Epw_cp8) will be helpful

<sup>3</sup> It's possible there are more references in *The Hobbit* movies, but I can't remember and I don't have copies of those scripts.